# updating database table from observable collection

Tags: silverlight, xaml, mvvm

I have bound a Data Grid to an ObservableCollection. It fills the grid with more than 200 records. Now user makes changes using editable control provided in the grid and finally clicks the save button to update the data back to database but I am not getting the idea how to update the modified collection back to the database because there is no PRIMARY KEY in the table.

The table has four columns apart from created by and modified by.

Like this i think i'll have to keep two collections. One older collection to compare against a new modified collection. I am quite new to think of better ideas.

What could be a simple and better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You should refer to this video by Nikhil Kothari [Developing with WCF Ria Services quickly and effectively](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/CL09).

There are several others on YouTube.